# I want transfer data js to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I don't know how to transfer data from JavaScript to Node.js.
I need to POST the `allUsers` array and the `user.username` property.

```
var allUsers = []
var user = {
  username: '',
  password: ''
}
var background = document.getElementById("bg")

function verify() {
  background.style.display = "inline"
  var usrname = document.getElementById("username").value
  var pswrd = document.getElementById("password").value
  user.username = usrname
  user.password = pswrd
  axios.get("dbid").then((response) => {
    var data = response.data
    for (let key in data) {
      var body = data[key]
      allUsers.push(body.user.username)
    }
    return verified();
  })
}

function verified() {
  var inc = allUsers.includes(user.username)
  if (user.password.length < 8) {
    alert('Şifreniz en az 8 karakter olmalıdır!');
    return background.style.display = "none";
  } else if (inc) {
    alert("Böyle bir mail adresi önceden kaydolmuş! Lütfen başka bir mail adresi deneyim.");
    return background.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    alert("Başarılı, G-mail adresinize bir doğrulama kodu gönderildi...");
    axios.post("dbid", {
      user: user
    })
    return background.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to post an array of data (in this case `allUsers`) and a string (`username`) you need to use the `JSON.stringify` method to convert the array to a JSON string.
Here is an async function that will post the data you need to send to the server:

```
const postData = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.post(<url-to-post>, {
            users: JSON.stringify(allUsers),
            username: user.username
        })
    } catch (err) {
        // Error posting data
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```